# How to distinguish two strings in a String?(How to prevent plain text injection)

Tags: java, string, code-injection

Say I have two randomly generated Strings.

What can I do to make a single String with the two Strings generated, while being able to split them to get the original two Strings for later use?

For example, I have "[aweiroj\3aoierjvg0_3409" and " 4093  w_/e9  ". How can I attach those two words into one variable while being able to split them to original two Strings?

My problem is, I can't seem to find a regex for .spit() because those two strings can have any chararacters(alpabet, integer, \, /, spaces...).

### EDIT

I just thought of a real life case where this could be used. [Sometimes](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-api/jDPYCNUZ4e4/mPaTIR3j5OoJ), sending plain text over network(HTTP) is better than xml or json. Slow server with fast broadband - use xml or json, fast server with slow broadband - use plain text. The answers below could prevent plain text injection. However, these methods are not benchmarked or tested, I would probably test these methods before actually using them.

Comment: Why don't you put them in a `List<String>`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You will need a delimiter of some kind.

Comment: How about using the length of original string and using that to split the concatenated string using substirng.

Comment: ah, the notorious [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is: Don't do that. Use an array, or a class with two data members, but combining the strings together into one string is probably a bad idea.

But if you have some truly obscure use case, you can:

1. Create a sufficiently-unique delimiter, like `"<<Jee Seok Yoon's Delimiter>>"`.

   ```
   final static String DELIM = "<<Jee Seok Yoon's Unique Delimiter>>";
   String a = /*...*/;
   String b = /*...*/;
   String combined = a + DELIM + b;

   int breakAt = combined.indexOf(DELIM);
   String a1 = combined.substring(0, breakAt);
   String b1 = combined.substring(breakAt + DELIM.length());
   ```
2. Have a simpler delimiter that you escape if present in the string.
3. Remember the length of the first string and store it in your unified string followed by an "end of length" delimiter.

   ```
   String a = /*...*/;
   String b = /*...*/;
   String combined = String.valueOf(a.length()) + "|" + a + b;

   int breakAt = combined.indexOf("|");
   int len = Integer.parseInt(combined.substring(0, breakAt), 10);
   String a1 = combined.substring(breakAt + 1, len);
   String b1 = combined.substring(breakAt + 1 + len);
   ```

*(Both code examples are **completely** off-the-cuff and untested.)*

Comment: #3 seems like the best option here.

Comment: @crush: Yeah (at least of the "if you really have to do this" set of options), I agree, not sure why it's #3. :-)

Comment: I thought sending plain text over http is better than json or xml performance-wise(this is somewhat [wrong](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-api/jDPYCNUZ4e4/mPaTIR3j5OoJ) depending on different situations). I asked this question to prevent plain text injection.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a Class that holds both Strings and is able to print them seperatly and combined.

This one simply extends ArrayList so you don't need to reimplement `add`, `get` and so on:

```
public class ConcatedString extends ArrayList<String>
{

    public String concated() {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        for (String string : this)
        {
            b.append(string);
        }

        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is a matter of serialization of some (obscure) kind, then there is at least one obvious way to do this.

Encode the strings using some encoding (HTML encoding is an easy and readable choice). Pick a character that the encoded strings cannot possibly contain, use that as a separator and concatenate them all.

Then, to retrieve, separate the strings by that character and decode the substrings using your initial method in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to work in every cases, you need to define 2 special characters :

- A delimiter character
- An escape character.

**1-Encoding :** When you concat the 2 String :

In both String,

- replace all characters which equal the **escape** character with 2 **escape** characters
- replace all characters which equal the **delimiter** character with **escape** + **delimiter**

then concat both String with the **delimiter** character between them.

**2-Decoding :** When you decode the String :

- If the current character is a **escape** character while the next one is also a **escape** character, replace it with only one **escape** character and skip 1 character.
- If the current character is a **escape** character while the next one is also a **delimiter** character, replace it with only one **delimiter** character and skip 1 character.
- If the current character is the **delimiter** character, then you are between the 2 original Strings.

Here is a working example :

```
//I make on purpose a bad choice for escape/delimiter characters
private static final char DELIMITER = '1';
private static final char ESCAPE = '2';

public static String encode(String s1, String s2){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  subEncode(s1, sb);

  sb.append(DELIMITER);

  subEncode(s2, sb);

  return sb.toString();
}

private static void subEncode(String s, StringBuilder sb) {
  for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if(c == ESCAPE) {
      sb.append(ESCAPE);
      sb.append(ESCAPE);
    }else if(c == DELIMITER) {
      sb.append(ESCAPE);
      sb.append(DELIMITER);
    }else {
      sb.append(c);
    }
  }
}

public static String[] decode(String encoded) {
  StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

  StringBuilder currentSb = sb1;
  char[] chars = encoded.toCharArray();
  for(int i = 0; i< chars.length ; i++) {

    if(chars[i] == ESCAPE) {
      if(chars.length < i+2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Malformed encoded String");
      }
      if(chars[i+1] == ESCAPE) {
        currentSb.append(ESCAPE);

      }else if(chars[i+1] == DELIMITER) {
        currentSb.append(DELIMITER);
      }
      i++;
    }else if(chars[i] == DELIMITER) {
      currentSb=sb2;
    }else {
      currentSb.append(chars[i]);
    }
  }
  return new String[]{sb1.toString(), sb2.toString()};
}
```

Test :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Nominal case :
  {
  String s1 = "aaa";
  String s2 = "bbb";
  System.out.println("Encoded : " + encode(s1, s2));
  System.out.println("Decoded" + Arrays.asList(decode(encode(s1,s2))));
  }

  //with bad characters :
  {
  String s1 = "111";
  String s2 = "222";
  System.out.println("Encoded : " + encode(s1, s2));
  System.out.println("Decoded" + Arrays.asList(decode(encode(s1,s2))));
  }

  //with random characters :
  {
    String s1 = "a11a1";
    String s2 = "1112bb22";
    System.out.println("Encoded : " + encode(s1, s2));
    System.out.println("Decoded" + Arrays.asList(decode(encode(s1,s2))));
  }
}
```

Output :

```
Encoded : aaa1bbb
Decoded[aaa, bbb]
Encoded : 2121211222222
Decoded[111, 222]
Encoded : a2121a21121212122bb2222
Decoded[a11a1, 1112bb22]
```

**Another way** to do this, format the encoded String using the following format :

```
size_of_str_1:str1|size_of_str2:str2
```

Example : if string1 is 'aa' and string2 is 'bbbb', the encoded String is : '2:aa|4:bbbb'.

You decode it via String#subString(). the "hard" part is to parse the string until you finished to read the size of the next String.